# Wrong expiration time in Azure IoT Hub messaging

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, amqp, azure-iot-hub

I have an *Asp.NET WebAPI* based backend for a game,
and I'm using *IoT Hub AMQP* to handle communication with game clients.

Different kind of messages require different Time-To-Live, and some of them are quite short (5-20 sec). I started noticing some random issues with message delivery, with negative feedbacks thrown almost immediately.

After a painful investigation, I discovered the cause was that **WebAPI and IoT Hub clocks were misaligned**, and so expiration time was triggered sooner or even immediately.

Now, the problem is that **IoT Hub client doesn't allow to set a Time-To-Live** (which would be correctly handled by Hub): instead, it forces you to specify an ExpirationTime, which is related to WebAPI clock and not the IoT Hub one.
I tried forcing some property manually ("iothub-enqueuedtime") with no luck.

On the other hand, I cannot rely on changing default IoT Hub expiration settings, because:

- they cannot handle TTL smaller than 60 seconds
- I need different TTL for different message types

Any idea on how to set a proper Time-To-Live or an Hub-based ExpirationTime when enqueueing a new message?